# Update Sharepoint List with elevated privileges

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, elevated-privileges

In a Webpart a user without any privileges needs to read and update a Sharepoint list.

Elevating privileges works ok for reading the list, but when I try to update the same list, throws a Exception. How is it possible to update a list with elevated privileges?

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{ 

SPSite oSite = SPControl.GetContextSite(HttpContext.Current);
SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb();
oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPListItemCollection listItems = oWeb.Lists["nameList"].Items;
SPListItem item = listItems.Add();

... 

item.Update(); // Throws Exception
});
```

Comment: The exception sends the message that "can't reach the trace caused by out of context".

Comment: Basically a duplicate. Check out this for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043312/sharepoint-query-with-elevated-privileges

Comment: I would suggest use using in the correct code you should not leave spsite and spweb objects un disposed. if you are not getting it directly from spcontext or the way you have written in code above the correct code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the creation of the SPSite.

The correct code:

```
SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID); 
SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID);                                 
listItems  = oWeb.Lists["nameList"];
```

Answer (score 1):

elevated privilages is used to add edit and delete all operations so thier must be some other problem kindly provide the exception details

Comment: Yes, was true. It was caused by the creation of the SPSite.

Comment: in this case you have to create a new instance of spsite and spweb and you do not have to consume a a site object from SPControl.GetContextSite(HttpContext.Current)